# JavaCard monitoring folder

Tags: java, xml, javacard

I want to write a two way application: applet for javacard and an application in C#.
I've got the C# covered but i want to know if with JavaCard i can monitor a folder on the memory and how would i go about doing that.

I have a shared folder let's call it temp in which i want to store buffer information between the simulated smartcard and the C# application. The C# application will only read from that folder and display the information, but also it will write requests towards the smartcard.

For example i simulate entering the PIN for the card. The applet will write a file containing available options and the C# application will read that file and display those options; from the C# app i will chose and option and write a request file in the same folder. This is when the smartcard which is monitoring that folder will read the request and issue a response. Can i make the smartcard monitor that folder?

I was thinking of using encrypted XML files for the request/response operations. But simple .txt files are good to.

I am limited to using JavaCard v2.2.1, and every operation has to be encrypted/decrypted.
(with the ciphering i have no problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can not monitor a Windows folder via Java Card Applet, As you want to did some monitoring via .Net application,So simpler solution could be 
a .Net application define some proprietary APDU (like get / set) and send to java card  (JC) application , whenever JC application receive these specific APDU it will return some result which is caught by .Net application & this is feasible to.